# Evaluate Keras model with scikit-learn metrics

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, model-evaluations

How does Keras calculate accuracy, precision, recall, and AUC?
I've created a model for categorical classification (i.e., multiple classes) by using `keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()` as loss function, and in the `model.compile()` method I've specified the following metrics:

```
METRICS = [
    keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='acc'),
    keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
    keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
    keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]
```

When I evaluate the model with `model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)` the result is the following:

> 147/147 - 1s - loss: 0.5127 - acc: 0.8073 - precision: 0.8437 - recall: 0.7696 - auc: 0.9537

Then, I want to compare its performance with the results obtained with other algorithms (e.g., `DecisionTreeClassifier()` implemented in scikit-learn).

To evaluate the other classifiers, I'm using the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score

print("AUC: %2.3f" % roc_auc_score(y_test, pred_bin))
print("ACC: %2.3f" % balanced_accuracy_score(lb.inverse_transform(y_test), pred))
print("PRE: %2.3f" % precision_score(lb.inverse_transform(y_test), pred, average='weighted'))
print("REC: %2.3f" % recall_score(lb.inverse_transform(y_test), pred, average='weighted'))
```

However, when I test the performance of my NN with this piece of code, I obtain the following results:

> ACC: 0.715 PRE: 0.801 REC: 0.807 AUC: 0.920

As you can note, the result differ from those obtained with `model.evaluate()` of Keras.
How can I fairly compare the different methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use class `KerasClassifier` from `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn`, which wraps a Keras model in a scikit-learn interface, so that it can be used like other scikit-learn models and then you could evaluate it with scikit-learn's scoring functions, e.g.:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

keras_model = ...
classifier = KerasClassifier(keras_model, batch_size=32)
y_pred_keras = classifier.predict(X_test).ravel()
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_keras)
auc_score = auc(fpr, tpr)
```

You can find more info on the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_sklearn_wrapper/), or googling around (e.g. [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-keras-deep-learning-models-scikit-learn-python/) and [this](https://www.dlology.com/blog/simple-guide-on-how-to-generate-roc-plot-for-keras-classifier/)).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will definitely try it. Just a curiosity: why the results are not the same?